# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 200, 200, 2) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 200, 200, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #allows us to see the image data
import os #to read and write from files
import cv2 #to manipulate data and create arrays
import tensorflow as tf 
import time
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

DIRECTORY = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/dataset/train" #where the image data is
data = DIRECTORY #loads in the data
MOLES = ["melanoma", "nevus"] #the two categories were are trying to analyse
training_dataset = [] #we will now need to make an array where all the data is, as opposed to two seperate files, to train the model.

for mole in MOLES: #iterates through the two files
    path = os.path.join(data, mole) #creates a path to the file
    class_num = MOLES.index(mole) #assigns the index 0 or 1 whether an image file is in the first or second file
    for img in os.listdir(path): #in the path       
        try:
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) #every file is read in
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) #resized, added to an array called new_array...
            training_dataset.append([new_array, class_num]) #...and given a number -- 0 or 1 -- based on if it is in the melanma or nevus file 
        except Exception as ex:
            pass

IMG_SIZE = 200 #what we want the max image size to be, both x and y

new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)) #uses the resize function
plt.imshow(new_array, cmap="gray") #shows the result
plt.show()

import random #as the dataset is simply the number 1 and 0, one after the other they aren't going to train the model

random.shuffle(training_dataset) #the order must be shuffled

X = []
y = []

for features, label in training_dataset:
  X.append(features)
  y.append(label)
    
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 2)
y = np.array(y)

X = X/255.0

#NAME = "melanoma-nevus-cnn-64x2-{}".format(int(time.time()))

dense_layers = [0]
layer_sizes = [64]
conv_layers = [2]

for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_size in layer_sizes:
        for conv_layer in conv_layers:        
            NAME = "test-{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
            tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs/{}'.format(NAME))
            print(NAME)
            model = Sequential()

            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
            model.add(Activation('relu'))
            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

            for l in range(conv_layer-1):
                model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3)))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

            model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
            
            for _ in range(dense_layer):
                model.add(Dense(layer_size))
                model.add(Activation('relu'))

            model.add(Dense(1))      
            model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

#model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy")
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#According to Kingma et al., 2014, the method [adam] is "computationally efficient, has little memory requirement, invariant to diagonal rescaling of gradients, and is well suited for problems that are large in terms of data/parameters".

model.fit(X, y, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10, validation_split = 0.3, callbacks=[tensorboard])

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 200  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (200, 200))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

prediction = model.predict([prepare("C:/Users/User/Desktop/dataset/test/melanoma/ISIC_0012758.jpg")])
prediction
```

***ERROR-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
2
3
#prediction = model.predict([prepare("C:/Users/User/Desktop/dataset/test/melanoma/ISIC_0012758.jpg")])
----> 4 prediction = model.predict([prepare("C:/Users/User/Desktop/dataset/test/melanoma/ISIC_0012758.jpg")])
5 prediction
 in prepare(filepath)
5     img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
6     new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (200, 200))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
----> 7     return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 2)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40000 into shape (200,200,2)***

---

I have been working on Python code on JuypterLabs and using Keras and Tensorboard to create a CNN and to try to train a model to sort images based on whether they are melanoma moles (cancerous) or nevus moles (regular). I've run into a problem on testing the model. When ever I try to run the test code it gives me the error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 200, 200, 2) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 200, 200, 2), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 200, 200, 1).

When I change the shape of the array to (-1, 200, 200, 2), as it was asking me to. I instead get the error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40000 into shape (200,200,2)

I've tried messing with the CNN shape but that doesn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: Hi @w1722412, The error states that you have created a model with input shape `(None, 200, 200, 2)` and calling the model with data of shape `(None, 200, 200, 1)`. As your input data is grayscale images, the last dimension should be 1. Hence, change the shape of X like `X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)`. Please find the working code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/7e666194a94ca2ce1c1cc809a070240a/untitled225.ipynb). Thank you!